# "Container is not defined" Google chart

Tags: api, charts, containers

I have solved my issue but can't answer it myself since I am too new to this site:

turns out I needed to use the following:

```
chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_today_div'));
```

I was using JQuery to access the element,  `$('#pie_today_div')`.  As of now the evidence points to the fact that the PieChart constructor has to have standard JS code, `document.getElementById('pie_today_div')`

Maybe something else going on, but changing the way I access the container element fixes my code

**ORIGINAL ISSUE FOR REFERENCE TO MY SOLUTION**

I am getting a "Container is not defined" error when I am trying to instantiate a Google PieChart object.

I validated my page at http://validator.w3.org/ and i get a pretty green banner saying it validates.

I receive no js errors when the page loads.  My Ajax call is making a full round trip with the data I want from the DB.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="/css/note.css?10022012" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/call/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/call/js/init.js?10042012-2"></script>
        <title>Call Stats</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="pie_today_link">Today Stats</a>
        <div id="pie_today_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**here is the js:**

```
function drawPieChartToday() {

    $.post('/call/ajax.php5',{
        action:'pieToday'
    }, function(ticketData) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Count');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Topic');
        for (var key in ticketData){
            data.addRow([key, ticketData[key]]);
        }
        options = {
            title: 'Issue Topics'
        };
        alert($('#pie_today_div').attr('id'));
        chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#pie_today_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    },'json');     
}
```

**here is my debugging code to make sure the element was being found:**
`alert($('#pie_today_div').attr('id'));`  <-- alerts "pie_today_div"

Comment: Look at my answer, the reason is that the jquery selector returns a set of matched elements (an array), even when selecting unique ids.

Comment: this was a very useful information, i need to remember it for the rest of my IT life.

Answer (score 35):

I'm not a jquery fan, but I think that $('#pie_today_div') returns a set of matched elements. The attribute computation works because (from jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)) it "gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements".

So try

```
chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#pie_today_div')[0]);
```

or directly

```
chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_today_div'));
```

Comment: how to use class name herer?

Comment: chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('.class-name')[0]);

Answer (score 17):

A container error is exactly that,  It is looking for the ID 
example:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

You WILL get this error “Container is not defined”  for Google Charts if you are missing
that ID 
Thus a Div with that chart_div id would fix this

Comment: Thanks for explaining why "Container not defined" occurs. I had mistakenly used "class" instead of "id". This helped!

Answer (score 1):

There must be line where you load the types of visualization you want to have in your web page. It looks like this

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
```

Here I am loading package `corechart`. Place this line as the first line after in the `<script>` tag inside your HTML page like index.html. That should solve he problem.

Answer (score 0):

use $timeout before init, it works well, else you need to destroy the instance

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to mention, this happened for me after a simple mistake. I changed

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(huh);
```

to the following in an effort to change the chart type:

```
var data = new google.visualization.BarChart(huh);
```

but this is all wrong, you change the chart where you mention the container:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```